# Writing a function to take character representing number and return corresponding integer

Tags: haskell

So far I have got this. I understand that I need to instantiate char to int but I am wondering if there is a way to say if a value as a character is entered 0-9 it will provide the integer value.

```
char_to_int :: Char -> Integer
char_to_int c = digitToInt c

main = do
    let number = '0'
    putStrLn "The number : "
    print (number)
    putStrLn "Integer equivalent to character entered"
    print ( char_to_int number)
```

I am getting this error:

```
Variable not in scope: digitToInt :: Char -> Integer
  |
6 | char_to_int c = digitToInt c
  |                 ^^^^^^^^^^
Failed, no modules loaded.
```

Any help would be appreciated :)

Comment: The actual error content is the few lines preceding what you've pasted here.

Comment: @DanielWagner: The original post contained the full error, but the syntax highlighter stripped it out, so I edited to fix that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to import the function. Furthermore it converts a `Char` to an `Int`, and thus only works for a *single* character:

```
import Data.Char (digitToInt)

char_to_int :: Char -> Int
char_to_int = digitToInt
```

But since you only here make an extra reference to the `digitToInt` function, you can use that directly:

```
import Data.Char (digitToInt)

main :: IO ()
main = do
    let number = '0'
    putStrLn "The number : "
    print (number)
    putStrLn "Integer equivalent to character entered"
    print (digitToInt number)
```

Comment: Thanks for this solution. Is there a way this can be done without importing the function or would it be a case of writing out each case for 0-9 manually?

Comment: @Stabbathehut: yes, in that case you implement it manually, or you could import the `ord`, and thus work with `ord c - ord '0'`.